# Cannot import org.opencv[...] in eclipse from Nvidia Tegra Developer Pack

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, import, tegra

I have downloaded https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack which has OpenCV for Tegra 2.4.3.2 included. **How to import opencV into the project.**

I have installed it and then run the Eclipse and import opencv samples but then I get lot of
and I cannot fix it

`The import org.opencv.imgproc cannot be resolved`

And I have no idead what I suppose to add to the project to make it work. There is no jar in the directory. **These are genuine samples from Nvidia pack so they should work.**

The console output:

```
16:00:48 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 4 - Mix Java+Native OpenCV ****
"D:\\Programowanie\\EclipseTegra\\cygwin\\bin\\bash" "D:\\Programowanie\\EclipseTegra\\android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build" NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\Programowanie\EclipseTegra\OpenCV-2.4.3.2-android-sdk-tadp\samples\tutorial-4-mixed
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/OpenCV-2.4.3.2-android-sdk-tadp/samples/tutorial-4-mixed
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
install -p /cygdrive/d/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/android-ndk-r8d/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "directory D:/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include D:/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++ "../../sdk/native/jni/include/opencv" "../../sdk/native/jni/include" D:/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include D:/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include" >> ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so
install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so
/cygdrive/d/Programowanie/EclipseTegra/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

16:00:51 Build Finished (took 2s.621ms)
```

ECLIPSE

[image]

Main directory
[image]

opencv directory

[image]

Comment: Have you added the jar which contains `org.opencv.imgproc` to your build path?

Comment: I wrote that I can't find any jars. There is only source code in java and native.

Comment: Then add the source code to eclipse and set a reference to it from your project. What about the samples? Can't you check how it is done there?

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you still are in this dilemma i.e. of finding  jar files in the open cv folder
.well, i too faced this situation and was going bonkers because of this. Now, i have found a simple solution to it.
simply find the jar files, in the 
`opencv>build>java` (most likely) 
or u can look up the jar files on google, where u may find a site where they can downloaded from, like..

> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencv241jar.htm

after downloading this, u just have to add the path to this file in the java build path

```
properties>java build path> add external jars
```

And voila!! :D
This is what solved my import errors. hope it does for you too or for whoever might face this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as [mentioned here](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/technologies/mobile/opencv_tegra_examples.htm#top):

1. Open Eclipse  TADP_directory/eclipse/
2. In the Package Explorer > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace > Next.
   Select root directory > Browse to  TADP_directory/OpenCV-2.4.8.2-Tegra-sdk > Open.
3. Select the OpenCV Library > Finish.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV sdk for Android is in directory ./sdk in opencv directory.

To solve this problem, you should do following steps:

1. Use menu File -> Import -> Existing project in your workspace. Press Browse button and locate OpenCV4Android SDK (OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk for example). DO NOT COPY INTO YOUR WORKSPACE, or you'll meet new problems.
2. In application project add a reference to the OpenCV Java SDK in Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add select OpenCV Library - 2.4.8. Besides, choose "is library" above in Library window.

Now it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

delete your OpenCV Library from your workspace and import it again like:

menu File -> Import -> Existing project in your workspace. Press Browse button and locate OpenCV4Android SDK ( /OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk)

then:
Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add select OpenCV Library - 2.4.8. Besides, choose "is library" above in Library.

Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects

That worked for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencv241jar.htm

download jar file and attach to project then problem slove it